# Scroll to top of a div with an animation like with <a href="#something"></a>

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.up img').on('click', function(){
        $('.content').animate({top: '0'}, 1500, 'swing');
    })
});
```

This didn't animate me to the top of the content which leaves me kind of confused really...

Comment: Your script looks like it tries to animate the div itself. What are you trying to accomplish? move the div, or scroll page to the div?

Comment: Scroll the page to the div. The above answer did just that, but I want to have a cool easing effect there as well and use ms instead of 'slow', clueless about those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does the element have the top property set?
you could get the elements position using scrollTop()

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#SOMETHING').offset().top - 20},1500, 'swing');
```

replace the SOMETHING id with the element you want to scroll to

Comment: This worked perfectly, but what the...? And how can I set the easing here? And why does replacing 'slow' with a number break it?

Comment: $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#hlogo').offset().top - 20}, 1500 , 'swing');